# Rider Unit Tests: Enqueue tests

Tags: user-interface, automated-tests, rider

In the Rider Test Runner UI, is there any way to say "when you've finished running the current set of tests that you're running ... then please run these ones"?

Nothing to do with the code defining the tests; I'm not looking for `[Order]`, or `[Repeat]` or `[Retry]`

Just about the Rider Unit Test interface.

Comment: Photo upload appears to be b0rked are there new rules about that or something?

Comment: no, there's no such setting, but I'd be curious to understand your requirements :) maybe you can elaborate a bit more on your question.

Comment: I'm not sure what more elaboration you're looking for? The interaction I've described seems fairly clear to me?

Comment: For me it's not clear why you want to run different sets of tests in a specific order, i. e. the motivation behind your question remains unclear. Therefore, you will only receive the answer _No, doesn't work_, while with a broader contexts there might be other options

Comment: I didn't say I wanted them run in a specific order

Comment: I said "There's currently some tests running ... and when those ones have finished I want you to run some more".

Comment: The motivation really isn't relevant to whether the UI is capable of doing this.

Comment: If you're looking for some other entirely different way to solve some perceived "underlying problem" that you assume I have ... please don't. If I had a narrow use case I would tell you about the underlying problem (take a look at my other questions - I do it very regularly). This is a question directly about the functionality available in the interface.